# Finding the area using double integrals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

We need to find the area of the shaded region , where curves are in polar forms as $r = 2 \sin\theta$ and $r=1$.

I formulated the double integral as follows :

We  find the area in the first quadrant and then multiply it by $2$ ,

Area of the circle $r=1$ in the first quadrant is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ , we need to subtract the area of the curve $r = 2\sin\theta$ from this , thus , area is given by :

$[\dfrac{\pi}{4} - \int^{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0}r.dr.d\theta]\times2$

Is this correct ?
The solution says  , " first consider $0< \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and then $\dfrac{\pi}{6}< \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ etc etc..... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral
$$ \int^{\pi/6}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0}r\;dr\;d\theta $$
gives only the area of the region colored red in the figure below:

[image]

To include the gray region from the first quadrant of
your unit circle, you also need to integrate from 
$\frac\pi6$ to $\frac\pi2$ as in the solution you were given.
(The integral is very simple.)

If you merely subtract the red region from the quarter circle, you
end up with the remaining gray region of the first quadrant *plus*
the white region of the first quadrant of the unit circle,
which is not at all the region you were trying to measure.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

$$[\int^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}_{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}\int^{1}_{0}rdrd\theta  \space + \space ...$$

$$... \space \int^{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}_{0}\int^{2\sin\theta}_{0}rdrd\theta]\times2$$

**Note:** I assume the two circles intersect when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ but didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

We can divide the region into four, find the area of the upper-right piece, and then multiply it as required.

Note that the lines cutting through the region is given by the equations 
$$\frac{1}{2} = r\sin\theta \mbox{ and } \theta=\pi/2.$$

We then take the upper-right piece, parameterised as 
$$ (\csc\theta)/2\le r \le 1,\mbox{ } \pi/6 \le \theta \le \pi/2.$$

Computing the area of this piece, we see that the area of the entire region is

$$A = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\int_{(\csc\theta)/2}^1 4r \mbox{  }drd\theta=\frac{1}{6}(4\pi - 3\sqrt{3}).$$